# Java8 Stream.filter doesn't work for lazy loading data

Tags: filter, java-stream, lazy-loading

Here is my code:

```
final ArrayList<DcpDealerQuotaModel> dealerQuotas = (ArrayList)getSearchResults(actionEvent);
        Map<PointOfServiceModel,List<DcpDealerQuotaModel>> dealerQuotaMap = 
dealerQuotas.stream().filter(item->(item.getDealer() == null || item.getDealer().getName().isEmpty())).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DcpDealerQuotaModel::getDealer));
```

When I execute debug to watch the data in dealerQuotas list, it shows its size is 8 and the dealer attributer of each DcpDealerQuotaModel is not null , but the dealer is only loaded when execute getter method. when I call dealerQuotas.stream().filter(item->(item.getDealer() == null || item.getDealer().getName().isEmpty())), it'll filter all dealerQuotas and return null, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your filter predicate filters out all the non null dealers and keeps only `null` dealers. Since there's no such dealers in your `stream` you get empty result. Change it like this,

```
.filter(item->item.getDealer() != null &&   !item.getDealer().getName().isEmpty())
```